# Characters do not get escaped in HISTTIMEFORMAT

Tags: command-line, bash

I have installed my first dualboot linux a couple of days ago. While I am customizing my terminal, I came by this problem. While escaping works correctly in the `PS1` variable, it’s not working in the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable.

```
WHITE="\e[97m"
BOLD="\e[1m"
RESET="\e[0m"  
PS1="$BOLD[\A - @\h:$WHITE\W\e[m]\n\\$ $RESET"
HISTTIMEFORMAT="$WHITE[%F %T] $RESET"
```

One way around this is using `echo` and `-e` as follows

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT=`echo -e $WHITE[%F %T] $RESET`
```

But I still want to know why the first method is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got it the other way around: some escape sequences are interpreted in `PS1` (cf. the Bash manual, [6.9 Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)). That's special for prompt variables, and other variables do not get the same treatment.

[`HISTTIMEFORMAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTTIMEFORMAT) is simply used as input to `strftime(2)`, which doesn't know anything about these escape sequences. So, you need something else to interpret the escape sequences (like `echo`, in this case).